# How to use COUNTIFS formula with multiple ranges?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am needing the COUNTIFS formula to return a value for multiples ranges.

Here is the formula I have used: =COUNTIFS(ALFRED!C20:G20,""<75%,ALFRED!I20:M20,""<75%)

This formula is giving me zero, but i have about 5 cells with a value of less than 75%

Thanks

Comment: I do not get the distinction between counting the values less then .75 and the cells whos values are less than .75.  Seems it is the same thing and countifs will do what you want.

Comment: Hi so this may explain what i am asking better: A1: 45%, A2: 78%, A3: 20%. When i used the COUNTIF formula, it will add cells A1 and A3 and return " 65% rather than the number 2. I need the formula to tell me "there are 2 cells with a value less than 75%" rather than ADDING those values.

Comment: Then you are using SUMIFS or SUMPRODUCT and not COUNTIFS.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include the formula you used.  If in a different language add the actual formula and your best attempt at translation.

Comment: Ok. Would this be correct? (i am also needing the count from a different sheet) =COUNTIFS(ALFRED!C20:C25,"<75%")                ?

Comment: Yes that is correct and it should count the number of cells that have a value less than 75%.  If you are getting something different please [edit] the post to include a photo or data that reproduces the error so we can try and replicate the issue.

Comment: ah, you need to change the format of the output to "general"  that is why you are getting 600%.

Comment: WOW, THANK YOU SO MUCH!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

`COUNTIFS()` is NOT counting how many cells meet each condition and then doing something like reporting how many that sums to.

It is checking which matching pairs (in this case) both meet that condition. So its an `AND` concept. This is why the range sizes and shapes have to be identical:  so Excel can easily pick the matching (pairs). (Three conditions, three cells being compared for success in all three (triplets, "and etc." as Ben Finegold might say).)

You may have five values that meet the conditions stated, but if they are not in matching pairs, they do not add to the count.

Say you have a smaller set of ranges. First condition's range is A1:A3 and the second one's range is M3:M5. The function checks to see if BOTH A1 and M3 meet their conditions, then if A2 and M4, then A3 and M5. A1:A3 might all meet their condition, but if none of M3:M5 do, the result is 0.

In this case, I am willing to bet that the five values you mention are NOT in matching pairs, wherein lieth the problem.

The `75%` vs `0.75` has no effect on things as both are acceptable.

You could try a couple different approaches as it seems you want to count in each range according to its own criteria (though they are the same values at the moment). One way would be the old school `test each cell in a range vs. a condition generating an array or TRUE/FALSE that you then multiply by 1 to convert to 0's and 1's, and wrap that in a SUM() to count them up:  and do it separately for each range in question so you control their individual criteria, and sum the piecewise results for a final total`.

Another would be to just use individual `COUNTIF()` functions for each portion adding them up as you go:

```
=COUNTIF(range_1,criteria_1) + COUNTIF(range_2,criteria_2)...
```

My preference, but some people just love the TRUE/FALSE conversion thing.